# Angular Material swipe gesture works hardly

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to add swipe functionality to a ng-repeated list of elements. However, the swiping works badly. Sometimes a swipe gestures (all on desktop) is recognized, but most of the times I'm click and swiping like a madman to achieve the expected result.

I am using Material Angular.

Code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="link in Links |  filter: { category: 'quick' }">
    <div ng-show="!link.show" md-swipe-left="link.show = true">
        <div class="lv-item ">
            <span href="{{link.url}}" class="no-select" target="_blank" >
                <div class="lv-title" class="no-select">{{link.title}}</div>
                    <small class="lv-small" class="no-select">{{link.description}}</small>
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="link.show" md-swipe-right="link.show = false">
            <div class="lv-item delete" >
                <button ng-click="deleteLink(link.id)">Verwijder</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
</div>
```

On the Angular Material swipe docpage (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/swipe) it seems easy and it works like a charm. However my implementation of the directive doesn't seem to work as it should. It rather lets me select the text inside the  element than swiping.

Also, I'd rather want the span to be a a href, but this only lets me drag the whole  element out of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that to assure a proper work of all material function you should use their containers and directives instead. So you should put all of that inside a md-content, and also use ng-ifs instead of ng-show on the swiped div. Which would result in something like that :

```
<md-content>
  <div ng-repeat="link in Links |  filter: { category: 'quick' }">
    <div ng-if="!link.show" md-swipe-left="link.show = true">
        <div class="lv-item ">
            <span href="{{link.url}}" class="no-select" target="_blank" >
                <div class="lv-title" class="no-select">{{link.title}}</div>
                    <small class="lv-small" class="no-select">{{link.description}}</small>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="link.show" md-swipe-right="link.show = false">
        <div class="lv-item delete" >
            <button ng-click="deleteLink(link.id)">Verwijder</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

I used this kind of code snippet on some md-sidenav and it works. By the way, if you're using chrome and use mobile view, the md-swipe-left is always triggered, doesn't matter if you swipe left, right, top or bottom.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It seems to improve the performance a bit (testing it on Firefox and Safari). However, after the first double swipe it continues to stutter.

Comment: Edit: It seems to be working just fine now! In addition to your post I've added a flex div on both the md-swipe'd elements. It now works like a charm! Thank you.